# Dynamically add javascript for new elements

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to dynamically add javascript for new elements I obtain & add to the page through ajax. So I can dynamically add javascript using the createElement("script") and appendChild for elements already on the page, but for new elements I just added through ajax, that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

btw I am adding new DOM elements using .innerHTML += instead of appendchild for each, since there is quite a lot of new elements. Does that matter?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "add javascript for new elements"?

Comment: I believe that `innerHTML` and `appendchild` serve entirely different purposes. You should be careful in your use of either.
You might also find it useful to play around with `style.display` and `style.visibilty` attributes.

Comment: I mean add  js for handling the new html elements that were added from the ajax response

Comment: it's quite a lot of stuff so I don't really want to use style.display to hide and then turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to employ the help of a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

With the help of jQuery, the work of tracking and working with dynamically added DOM elements becomes trivial:

$.(document).on("click","#MyElement",function(){
  //do stuff
});

Good luck!

Comment: ugh yes, i totally forgot about .live

Comment: @user1181950 Cool.  If it helped, please vote up and accept the answer.  Thanks and let me know if I can be of further help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dynamically adding javascript, you should set aside dedicated functions in your `<script>` section in the header or as a separately sourced file. Once your elements are added, you should add event handlers that call these dedicated functions without needing to add javascript dynamically.

Comment: ok, if that is the right way to do it, then i can do that easily. But just so I know, is there a way to do the above at all? thanks!

Comment: So I actually tried what you suggested. Have the js already loaded in page, and then adding only the html from ajax. Does it matter i am using jQuery for the javascript as well?

Comment: @user1181950 I'm not so knowledgeable on jQuery, but I believe you should be able to do so.
As for adding javascript dynamically, I am not certain. Maybe you can try looking into [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have loaded your contents to a container called with `id="container"` you might wanna use a selector like

`$("#container img")`

to get the elements and set the event handlers.

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/PTcw8/5/

Comment: yea as mentioned below, i totally forgot about .live in jquery ><